# Eclipse doesn't start after installing VisualVM plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, visualvm

I tried to install the VisualVM plugin. Now eclipse doesn't start and my log file looks like:

```
!SESSION 2014-11-27 16:40:55.574 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.6.0_39
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clean -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2014-11-27 16:41:01.775
!MESSAGE Unable to find feature.xml in directory: C:\Program Files\eclipse\features\VisualVM_Launcher_1.1.1.jar
```

I copied all files from zip to the right place!

Even starting eclipse with following params -clean -clearPersistedState don't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the `VisualVM_Launcher_1.1.1.jar` file into the features folder won't work, it needs to be a folder not a file. The Visual VM plugin is distributed as a P2 update site, so the best way to install it is to unzip it to a temporary folder then use:

```
Help->Install New Software...->Add->Local
```

Point it at your temporary folder to add the update site. The install wizard will then let you select and install the plugin.

Comment: I am trying to delete it cause I can't eclipse anymore!

Comment: Delete the `VisualVM_Launcher_1.1.1.jar` file from the features folder. Does Eclipse start after doing that?